# IPTables -m set unknown option

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, ubuntu-20.04

I'm having trouble seting-up iptables on Ubuntu 20.04.

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

```
# iptables -A INPUT -m set -–match-set cf src -p tcp -m multiport –dports http,https -j ACCEPT
iptables v1.8.4 (legacy): unknown option "set"
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

My `cf` has the cloudflare ip's:

```
for x in $(curl https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v4); do ipset add cf $x; done
```

Comment: Please post the output of `uname -a`

Comment: @MichaelHampton `Linux server.example.com 5.4.0-80-generic #90-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 9 22:49:44 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 2):

Incorrect syntax:

> ```
> # iptables -A INPUT -m set -–match-set cf src -p tcp -m multiport –dports http,https -j ACCEPT
> ```

Correct syntax:

```
# iptables -A INPUT -m set --match-set cf src -p tcp -m multiport --dports http,https -j ACCEPT
```

At two places, one or two `‐` ([hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen): u002d) were replaced with a `–` ([en dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#En_dash): u2013). Be careful when using word processors not designed for programming when copying scripts through them: they can alter what looks like punctuation to them but is a syntax that must not be altered. Same goes when retrieving this from some web sites not handling things correctly or even some PDF documents.